# Fetch object with aggregations on related table

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, aggregate

How to fetch object with aggregations on related table using eloquent laravel 4.

sql structre:

```
TABLE companies
id PRIMARY KEY
title TEXT
...

TABLE ratings
id PRIMATRY KEY
company_id FK KEY
some_rating_1 INTEGER  -- for example rating for delivery
some_rating_2 INTEGER  -- for example rating for customer service
some_rating_2 INTEGER  -- for example rating for price
...
```

I want to get collection of companies with aggregated ratings.

I tried to something like below but I cant append AVG to GET in closure.

```
Company::with(['ratings' => function($query) {
        $query->avg('some_rating_1');
        $query->avg('some_rating_2');
        $query->avg('some_rating_3');
        $query->get(['company_id', 'some_rating_1']);
    }])->get();
```

Anybody know can I fetch companies with aggergation on rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself, here solution:

```
Company::with(['ratings' => function($query) {
        $query->select(
            'company_id',
            DB::raw('round(avg(rating_overall)::numeric, 2) as rating_overall'),
            DB::raw('round(avg(some_rating_1)::numeric, 2) as rating_fast'),
            DB::raw('round(avg(some_rating_2)::numeric, 2) as rating_quality'),
            DB::raw('round(avg(some_rating_3)::numeric, 2) as rating_service'),
            DB::raw('count(company_id) as rating_amount'),
            DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN review IS NOT NULL THEN 1 else 0 END) as review_amount')
        )->groupBy('detective_id');
```

The first attribute in subquery '**company_id**' FK is **necessary** - I don't know why but without it laravel returns empty set ratings[]. It was the most confusing me thing in solving this problem.

In next attribute should we use **DB::raw** query instead of Eloquent avg() method.

Additional feature in this solution is **round**'ing number in PostgreSQL which should be cnoverted from float to **numeric** first and CASE statement counting by sum() only ratings which have **review** specified.

Of course query results should be stored in cache using Cache::**remember** method.